# Using an external HD as my applications folder

Tags: macos, applications, external-disk

I need to install more applications - can I use my external HD (samsung T5) and add an additional applications folder? I have loads of space on it and it the speeds are great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use an external drive to keep (install) apps.

You should be fine. You don't need to specifically create a folder named **Applications** on the external drive. Any name or directory hierarchy should be fine.

macOS apps are generally made available as bundles (.app extension) which is technically a directory appearing as a single file to the user (with a specialized structure). An app bundle could be placed **anywhere** on secondary storage and the app can be used without any difference.

By default, apps are installed in boot volume's `/Applications` directory and are automatically made available to all the users on macOS. Keeping an app bundle in a folder/drive only accessible to you limits the app available to you.

On a related note, it is worth mentioning for the macOS newcomers that installing/uninstalling an app in macOS is as simple affair as copying/trashing the app's *.app file*.

Comment: Also, if you have apps in more than one place, a launcher app becomes additionally helpful. I use the free version of LaunchBar which does thousands more things in addition to launching apps, like creating symbolic links (could help you put external apps back into the main Applications folder). Yu simply hit a shortcut to launch Launchbar then type a couple of letters in the app name and it will guess it (and it learns the more you use apps).